# if else statement not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, if-statement

Would appreciate any help to a newbie here. I have a simple if/else if statement that for some reason only gets to the second condition, even if the third is met. I've tried adding else to the end, tried pretty much everything but still nothing. I know it's not working, because I added the alert triggers and no matter what it never gets to the third condition. What am I missing here? I've looked around a lot so I'm sorry if I'm beating a dead horse here but I couldn't find a solution. I should note that I'm trying to get the conditions on the change of a selection drop-down box. Thanks!!!

My code:

```
$('#table_two select:eq(6)').change(function(e){

var allDiv = $('#table_two,#table_three,#table_four');
var parBoxOne = $('#par_one').val();

var totalOne = 1 - parBoxOne;
var totalTwo = 2 - parBoxOne;


if ($(this).val() == "made_shot"){
$(allDiv).hide();
$('#score_one').val(totalOne);
$('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
alert('ACE!!');
}

else if ($(this).val() == 'green', 'trees', 'fairway', 'rough', 'sand' ){
$('#score_one').val(totalOne);
$('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
$('#table_two').hide();
$('#butt_two').html('Show stroke');
alert('triggered two');
}

else if ($(this).val() == 'other', 'penalty_water', 'penalty_ob', 'penalty_sand' ){
$('#score_one').val(totalTwo);
$('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
$('#table_two').hide();
alert('triggered three');
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another apporoach:

```
switch($(this).val()){
    case 'made_shot':
        $(allDiv).hide();
        $('#score_one').val(totalOne);
        $('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
        alert('ACE!!');
        break;

    case 'green':
    case 'trees':
    case 'fairway':
    case 'rough':
    case 'sand':
        $('#score_one').val(totalOne);
        $('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
        $('#table_two').hide();
        $('#butt_two').html('Show stroke');
        alert('triggered two');
        break;

    case 'other':
    case 'penalty_water':
    case 'penalty_ob':
    case 'penalty_sand':
        $('#score_one').val(totalTwo);
        $('#score_total').val($('.score_input').val());
        $('#table_two').hide();
        alert('triggered three');
        break;
    }
```

Comment: +1. Other answers explained why the original didn't work, but when all the if conditions are testing the same value a switch statement makes more sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you, the other answers already explained where he is going wrong.

Comment: it works!! Thanks for taking your time to explain this to a noob like me. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

You cant combine multiple conditions in an if statement using commas:

<del>`if ($(this).val() == 'green', 'trees', 'fairway', 'rough', 'sand' )`</del>

Instead, you can make the value list into an array and check if your value is in the array:

```
var stuff = ['green', 'trees', 'fairway', 'rough', 'sand'];
if ( $.inArray($(this).val(), stuff ) >= 0 )
```

To combine multiple conditions in an if, the syntax is this (much longer than above):

```
if ($(this).val() == 'green' || $(this).val() == 'trees' || ... )
```

Comment: @raminson Sorry, typo. Thanks for pointing out the error though

Comment: @beatmusic67 No problem, glad to help. If this (or any other) answer was helpful, please consider 'accepting' it by clicking the check mark on the left (under the vote count) to turn it green. You can only accept one answer, so accept whichever you feel helped you best.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot campare strings in this way, you can use `$.inArray()` function 
instead and create an array of values:

> **jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex] )**

```
 if($.inArray($(this).val(), ['green', 'trees', 'fairway', 'rough', 'sand']) != -1) {

 }
```